# Asp.Net MVC Ninject and Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, ninject, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a site that uses Ninject for dependency injection and I have Routing defined within a Bootstrapper class like so:

```
    public void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

        Routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{pageTitle}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Page", pageTitle = "Index" }
        );

        Routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

I have added an Area to the project but the default AdminAreaRegistration is not registering the root

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Where or how do I register the Area with Ninject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample project comming with the source code has now an area. Take a look at it. https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/zipball/master

Comment: Cheers, I was over thinking the issue, It's as simple as just adding an area to the project!

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the source project and referencing it against my own really was a big help! ( :

Answer (score 2):

are you calling RegisterAllAreas()?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

note it must be called *before* RegisterRoutes().

Comment: thanks for your response. I already have this in:         protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
          RegisterAllControllersIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var bootstrapper = Kernel.Get<Bootstrapper>();
            bootstrapper.RegisterRoutes();
        }

Answer (score 2):

Have you resolved this issue?

I have the problem where my NinjectControllerFactory is not resolving urls that reference controllers defined in areas. I get the following message:

> The IControllerFactory 'myWebSite.WebUI.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'admin'.

If I move the controller to the root Controllers folder, it will resolve the url.

Comment: @user515290 - Cheers I'll have a look at this